# What would be the benefit of adding a function name to an object declaration?

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

For instance, when I assign a function as a property of an object declaration,  my loader for Webpack, which is babel-loader, will automatically add a function name? For instance, let’s say I have the following compare function:

```
var utils = {
  compare: function (a, b) {
    if (parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0]) === 0) {
      return parseFloat(a[1]) - parseFloat(b[1]);
    }
    else {
      return parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Webpack will compile it to the following:

```
var utils = {
  compare: function compare(a, b) {

    if (parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0]) === 0) {
      return parseFloat(a[1]) - parseFloat(b[1]);
    } else {
      return parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

[compare: function (a,b) has been changed to compare: function **compare** (a,b)]

Comment: It is useful for debugging, but painful to write.

Comment: It's not webpack that does it, but a loader

Comment: @elclanrs would you be kind enough to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Razroo-Chief: in devtools you would see the name of the function instead of (anonymous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted in the question there would indeed be little to no benefit. However, to recursively call an anonymous function you need to give it a name (at least in newer versions of javascript). This syntax has a name. It's called the [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression).

In older versions of javascript, the `arguments` object has a property called `.callee` that refers to the function. This could be used to recurse into an anonymous function:

```
var sum = function(numbers){
    var n = numbers.pop();
    if (numbers.length) {
        return n + arguments.callee(numbers);
    }
    return n;
}
```

The `arguments.callee` property has been deprecated in ES5. Therefore in current (and newer) versions of javascript you need to use a named function expression to do recursion on an anonymous function:

```
var sum = function s (numbers){
    var n = numbers.pop();
    if (numbers.length) {
        return n + s(numbers);
    }
    return n;
}
```

---

Note, that according to the specification, the name of a named function expression is private to the function itself. Therefore, in a non-buggy javascript interpreter/compiler the second example above should not create a function named `s()` outside of the anonymous function `sum()`. However, some ES4 implementations (older browsers) were known to be broken and would create both `s()` and `sum()`. Apart from the name leak the named function expression syntax works in all browsers released in the last 10 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a good practice to name all your functions for debugging and recursion purposes. Babel does that on the transpiled code with the loader, is not Webpack's work.